# store unix timestamp from php file into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I have this code:

```
$mysqldate = date(time());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO permissions (date)
VALUES ('$mysqldate')");
```

I escape before I insert also, but my problem is that the time is getting stored as all 0s. I was wondering what column datatype in mysql would store something like:

```
1311602030
```

a unix timestamp, and then would properly allow me to order by most recent dates on a query.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use mysql timestamps?

Comment: What is the data type of the `date` column?  You are trying to insert an integer.  Also, I would highly recommend using a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column instead of storing integers.  You can use the MySQL function NOW() to insert the current time into a DATETIME/TIMESTAMP column.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If timestamp column in database is of type INTEGER you can do

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO permissions (date) VALUES ('".time()."')");
```

As integer value you can also do sort operation and convert it via `date()` function from PHP back to a readable date/time format.
If timestamp column in database is of type DATETIME you can do

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO permissions (date) VALUES ('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')");
```

or

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO permissions (date) VALUES (NOW())");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO permissions (date) VALUES ('".$mysqldate."')");
```

Answer (score 1):

the date() function needs a string as the 1st argument, which is the format. the time(), should be the 2nd argument, like: date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()). this will return a string, that you can use with a DATETIME column. other than that, if you want to store a unix timestamp, just use an INT column. so you can store the result of time() directly, without calling date. (or, as i said before, format the timestamp using date() with a valid format string and use a DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP column). see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

EDIT: the 0's you are seeing, are there because mysql did not recognice the format you used for the column (so if you are using a DATE column but you're passing it the wrong format, it is not recogniced, so a 0 is saved)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO permissions (date) VALUES ('$mysqldate')");
```